# Using 'open cursor' as 'execute immediate'

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to use open cursor as a substitute for execute immediate because my SQL statement could return multiple records.

```
 open cur1 for rule_sql;
   loop        
    dbms_output.put_line(cur1.rule_id);
   end loop;
 close cur1;
```

It throws an error saying: "PLS-00487: Invalid reference to variable 'CUR1'"

Has anyone had similar issues? Any help is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cursor is just a pointer to a result set. To reference its contents you need to `fetch` it into a variable. Note that the variable must be a record type which matches the projection of the query. This may be hard if you're using dynamic SQL to implement a fluid set of columns.

Anyway, something like this:

```
declare
    cur1 sys_refcursor;
   Type cur_rec is record (
        rule_id number,
        rule_desc varchar2(32));

    row1 cur_rec;
    ....
Begin
     ...
     open cur1 for stmt;
     for row1 in cur1 loop
           Dbms_output.put_line(row1.rule_id);
    End loop;
    ....
End;
```

---

> "If I do not know the type of columns in the result then I cannot create a variable to capture the cursor values."

Life is more complicated when you don't know the projection of your query at compile time. You can't use Native Dynamic SQL anymore, you need to go full DBMS_SQL.

In 11g Oracle introduced the so-called Method 4 Dynamic SQL. This allows us to handle variable projections at the cost of a lot more code. Adrian Billington wrote an excellent introduction to this on his Oracle-developer.net site. [Check it out](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=422)

Comment: Hi @APC: Thanks a lot for taking time.. If I do not know the type of columns in the result then I cannot create a variable to capture the cursor values.. is it?

Comment: Life gets harder. Which version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: I am using the version 4.1.5 :)

Comment: No I meant the database version. 11gR2? 12c?

Answer (score 1):

You have missed the `fetch` statement - see [Example 7.4 in docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/dynamic.htm#BHCGEFCA)

```
open cur1 for rule_sql;
loop        
  fetch cur1 into my_row_variable;
  exit when cur1%notfound;
  dbms_output.put_line(cur1.rule_id);
end loop;
close cur1;
```

Comment: hi @tony : if I do not know if there will be a column by name 'rule_id' and i want to see the whole cursor output.. is there a possibility to that? I have tried put_line(cur1) but that doesnt work.

Comment: In that case you will need to use the [DBMS_SQL package](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_sql.htm#ARPLS058) and the solution is a lot more complicated.  There are various examples in that documentation.